# Why Dialog in Flutter web closed when i click on TextField from Iphone or Ipad

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I have a dialog with a login form and when I want to enter text from my cell phone when I open the keyboard, the dialog closes, this bug is not present when I run flutter on ios or android, I do it in the web

```
showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
                          content: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: ListBody(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                TextFormField(
                                  autofocus: true,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Email',
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 12),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                    ),
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: colorInputField,
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: colorBackgroundSecondary,
                                        width: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: colorPrimary,
                                        width: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                                      return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  controller: emailController,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            TextButton(
                              child: const Text('Approve'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
```

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12D0lwSk8UG9IbxKIdy-qjGCmpMxkjvpG/view?usp=sharing) to the video where the error is visible

I thought that the problem was with controllers that rebuild widgets, but I removed them and still the dialog closed when I clicked on the textField, a similar problem with modal

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think this is happening because the dialog tries to reuse the same context as the keypad. So wrap your dialog in a new state that will give access to a different context

Comment: I started debugging the code and noticed that the problem was even deeper. I tried to simply click on the textFormField in the scaffold column and the input keyboard on my phone opened and immediately closed(

Comment: having a dialog open and keyboard open is prone to  such issues. Could you use a page instead of a dialog?

Comment: It seems to me that we have a misunderstanding, I mean that even without alertDialog, clicking on the TextFormField, the keyboard opens and closes immediately